# Is there a way to disable Alt Gr + Tab in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

I have a ERP software here that used the short cut Alt Gr + Tab in certain windows to jump between different tables. In WinXP this worked fine, now after upgrading to Win7, this does the same thing as Alt+Tab, but the window then sticks. I want to use that shortcut (Alt Gr + Tab) for the function in the ERP software, so is there a way to disable that function in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to achieve this.

Use this script to overwrite the function.

```
$<^>!{Tab}::
IfWinActive ahk_class TheNameOfYourWindow
   Send <^>!{Tab} 
return
```

This script will disable the AltGr + Tab hotkey, when the window of your ERP-software isn't active and overwrite the function. 
**Attention** You have to change the "TheNameOfYourWindow" to the real name of your window of course.

As I'm currently not on a windows-system, I wrote that without checking if its correct.
If this isn't the way you look for or it won't work, you can also have a look at the autohotkey *[Overriding Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm)* site.